# Rapid Spring REST development, like Apigility for PHP?

Tags: java, api

I am aware of Spring Roo, but is there an app/interface similar to [Apigility](https://apigility.org/) that is made for Spring projects?

Apiligilty is a frontend web client that allows you to "build" REST endpoints by using a form/wizard builder. You select the Action, ContentType, etc and it generates the files, controllers, to be used for a PHP (Zend) project. Then all you have to do is write in your service code.

I am looking for something that can quickly automate some of the common code needed for writing a RESTful API for my application.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you elaborate a bit more what you need and why Spring Roo doesn't do it? Please do read [this meta](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1/94) on how to ask for alternatives here on the site. Currently I have to know Apigility to be able to answer your question, which is too bad because while I'm a capable Java developer, I have no idea what that is. The questions here work best if all the information needed to provide a proper answer are in the question itself.